# Laravel 9 test dusk does not work on Docker with selenium/standalone-chrome

Tags: php, laravel, docker, selenium, laravel-dusk

I installed dusk based on the laravel document, but I can't run a test dusk on docker interactive mode. I searched the web without finding the correct configuration.
This is a part of the docker-compose file:

```
services:
  php-apache:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app_php
    ports:
        - '8081:80'
    volumes:
      - ./core:/var/www/app
      - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    links:
      - selenium
    depends_on:
      - database    
    networks:
      - mysite

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:104.0
    container_name: selenium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - mysite
```

And this is the error I get:

`1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample TypeError: Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct(): Argument #1 ($capabilities) must be of type array, null given, called in /var/www/app/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php on line 648`

I've put in two days to solve the problem. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

On your duskTestCase.php file, on the driver function, add these 2 lines to the options:

```
       '--whitelisted-ips=""',
       '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
```

1st line to allow the containers to communicate, 2nd to solve issue on dev-shm mount reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/1267

also on the same driver function,  the url must be pointing to your selenium container:

```
return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).